# Getting intensity values from image to make a Gaussian fit

Tags: image-processing

To get the pixel values (intensity) from an image I tried

```
data = PixelValue[image, {1;;1024, 1;;371}, "Byte"]
data = [[All, 1]]
```

I expected to get a matrix, but I get intensity information, but there is no matrix, but just a lot lists.

What should I do? My final aim is Gaussian fitting with particles image.

Comment: In Mathematica a matrix is represented by a list of lists.

Comment: Would MatrixForm help?

Comment: Note that images usually are sRGB-encoded. You may want to convert your image to [Linear RGB](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15596/280) before fitting.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: Note that this is only true for consumer cameras. Industrial cameras usually measure brightness linearly. (At least the ones I've worked with)

Comment: @nike Thanks. As I understand, industrial cameras probably never save images as JPG (at least by default). Which image format(s) do they prefer?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: I am working e.g. with expensive Photron CMOS cameras, they export as png.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov: The industrial cameras I work with don't save images at all. You're expected to get the images via GigE interface, and save them yourself, usually as png, tiff (for 16bit color depth) or bmp format.

Comment: You may be interested in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27642/fitting-a-two-dimensional-gaussian-to-a-set-of-2d-pixels

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of lists of pixel values of that part of the image, you'd use the following. It's going to give results in the range [0,1].

```
ImageData@ImageTake[image,{1,1024},{1,371}]
```

You could use `//MatrixForm` at the end of that to get a giant matrix, but beware, it could be a little intensive to display a matrix that big. Like, crash-your-kernel intensive!

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "Gaussian fitting with particles image", maybe you could clarify. But if you meant trying to find some linear transform that will make the image's histogram look vaguely gaussian, you could use this, where `mu` is the mean of your gaussian and `sigma` is the standard deviation.

```
i = ImageTake[image,{1,1024},{1,371}];
HistogramTransform[image,NormalDistribution[mu, sigma]]
```

Good luck!